# COMPSs application blocked

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hpc, compss

When executing the sample application **increment** given in the manual (http://compss.bsc.es/releases/compss/latest/docs/COMPSs_User_Manual_App_Exec.pdf) the runtime gets blocked and no error message is displayed in the terminal.

OUTPUT:

```
$ runcompss increment.Increment 3 1 2 3
Using default location for project file: /opt/COMPSs/Runtime/configuration/xml/projects/project.xml
Using default location for resources file: /opt/COMPSs/Runtime/configuration/xml/resources/resources.xml

----------------- Executing increment.Increment --------------------------

WARNING: IT Properties file is null. Setting default values
[   API]  -  Deploying COMPSs Runtime v1.3 
[   API]  -  Starting COMPSs Runtime v1.3
Initial counter values:
- Counter1 value is 1
- Counter2 value is 2
- Counter3 value is 3
```

How can I know what is blocking my application?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**
Checking the $HOME/.COMPSs/increment*/runtime.log all the tasks seem to be blocked:

```
grep "Blocked" runtime.log 
[(410)(2016-03-04 15:48:09,864)       TaskScheduler]    @scheduleTask     -  Blocked: Task(1, increment) 
[(411)(2016-03-04 15:48:09,865)       TaskScheduler]    @scheduleTask     -  Blocked: Task(2, increment) 
[(412)(2016-03-04 15:48:09,866)       TaskScheduler]    @scheduleTask     -  Blocked: Task(3, increment)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The runtime.log must be in the home folder of the user who has executed runcompss

```
$HOME/.COMPSs/increment*
```

**EDIT:** If all tasks are blocked, check if there are constraints defined in IncrementItf.java matches with the description in the resources.xml. Another possible problem is that the resources couldn't be started.

Comment: Thank you! I found it but is very huge. Grepping it i can see that all my tasks are remaining blocked. Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: You could have a look into the worker's log to see if there is something wrong there. They should be inside:

`$HOME/.COMPSs/increment*/workers`

Comment: Have you defined constraints in the tasks?

Answer (score 3):

Tasks get blocked for two reasons:

- Resources are not properly configured on the xml files.
- The available resources do not fulfill the task constraints (does not apply in the simple example)

You should check the project and resources xml files. There should be one resource with the same name in both files.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the runtime.log file, it contains all the master's output.

Comment: And where can I find the runtime.log file?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer